# how to set up permissions in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, user-permissions

I recently successfully created a new neo4j database with the import tool.  Now, I'd like to actually access the database on my Ubunutu laptop.

To do so, I edited `conf/neo4j-server.properties` appropriately, to point to the correct location.

Upon attempting `sudo service neo4j-service start`, I get the error

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [10810]... waiting for server to be ready.. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

I check the logs, and I see a lot of complaining about permissions.

From the logs,

```
2016-05-15 01:58:31.143-0700 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1b68b9a4' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.  
...  
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/monica/new_database_directory/messages.log (Permission denied)  
...  
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/monica/new_database_directory/messages.log (Permission denied)  
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/monica/new_database_directory/messages.log (Permission denied)
```

Googling around, I see that some others have had this problem.

However, I am not sure how to continue, since I don't fully understand the problem. I don't understand how neo4j expects to be used. When and where is the user specified? Do I need to change a Neo4J config file somewhere to allow myself permission? Or do I need to change permissions on the directory I just created...and if so, how do I know which user to change it to?

I'm interested in understanding more about how neo4j is configured in this situation, not only just how to make it work for me. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neo4j, running as a service, must have ownership of the folder where you placed the database (such as `/var/lib/neo4j/data`). Your database is elsewhere, and only you have access currently (as you, the logged-in user, created that database folder).

Try changing permissions to that entire data folder (recursively), with:

`sudo chown -R neo4j:adm /home/monica/new_database_directory`

If you look at the existing /var/lib/neo4j folder, the ownership should match that (`neo4j:adm`). After running the `chown` command, your new data folder should have the same ownership.

Then try starting the service again.

Comment: How does one see the ownership of lib/neo4j? (neo4j:adm throws `illegal group name` for me)

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your logs here as well?

If I had to guess it is not talking about neo4j permissions, but rather file permissions.  Can you check that whichever account is running the neo4j server (probably neo4j user) has the correct permissions on the data path?

Comment: How can I find out which account is configured to run neo4j? I think I'm using it under my regular username. I installed with default settings. And I get `WARNING: not changing user` when it starts, which I think means I'm not the root user.